# $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}E_n\cup\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_n\subset\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}(E_n\cup F_n)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration by James Yeh, the author claims that given two sequences $(E_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ and $(F_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ of a set $X$,

$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}E_n\cup\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_n\subset\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}(E_n\cup F_n)$$

with the following steps:

$x \in \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}E_n\cup\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_n \text{ then, }x \in \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}E_n\text{ or }\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_n $

If $x \in \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}E_n$, $x\in E_n$ for all but finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$

**(1): Then, $x\in E_n \cup F_n$ for all but finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$**

And so, $x \in\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}(E_n\cup F_n)$. Similar logic for $x \in  \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_n$.

---

I don't agree with **(1)** as for all we know $x$ could be in infinitely many $F_n$ which implies that $x\in E_n \cup F_n$ for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$...

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in E_n$ for all but finitely many $n$, then it must be the case that $x\in E_n\cup F_n$ for all but finitely many $n$ (in fact $x\in E_n\cup F_n$ for at least the same $n$ for which $x\in E_n$) since $E_n$ is a subset of $E_n\cup F_n$.

Comment: Oh! So I think I was saying for all we know, $x\in E_n\cup F_n$ for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ but are you saying, $x$ must also at least be in $x\in E_n\cup F_n$ where $n$ is greater or equal to the same n for which $x\in E_n$ which is the same as $x\in E_n\cup F_n$ for all but finitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Darius: We know that there is some $N$ so $x\in E_n$ for all $n\ge N$. Hence we know that $x\in E_n\cup F_n$ if $n\ge N$.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying. My question was that even if $x\in F_n$ for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$, x is at least in $E_n \cup F_n$ for all but finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ since  $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}(E_n \cup F_n) \subset \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(E_n \cup F_n)$?